# Multiple smtp servers in symfony mailer

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-mailer

I am trying to configure sending emails with Symfony mailer component. It perfectly works with one DNS (which I have in my .env file).
But I want to have 2 of them for example.
How can I configure it? I haven't found anything sensible in the documentation.

Here is my mailer.YAML

```
framework:
    mailer:
        dsn: '%env(MAILER_DSN)%'
```

I would like to have something like:

```
    framework:
        mailer_default:
            dsn: '%env(MAILER_DSN1)%'
        mailer_second:
            dsn: '%env(MAILER_DSN2)%'
```

But such an option is not possible, unfortunately.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can send to multiple transports according to the documentation [here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/mailer.html#multiple-email-transports)

Example, like this:

```
# config/packages/mailer.yaml
framework:
    mailer:
        transports:
            main: '%env(MAILER_DSN)%'
            alternative: '%env(MAILER_DSN_IMPORTANT)%'
```

By default the first transport is used. The other transports can be selected by adding an X-Transport header (which Mailer will remove automatically from the final email):

```
// Send using first transport ("main"):
$mailer->send($email);

// ... or use the transport "alternative":
$email->getHeaders()->addTextHeader('X-Transport', 'alternative');
$mailer->send($email);
```